# How do I pull out the attributes or field names from a dataclass?

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I have a dataclass, say `Car`:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Car:
    make: str
    model: str
    color: hex
    owner: Owner
```

How do I pull out the attributes or fields of the dataclass in a list?, e.g.

```
attributes = ['make', 'model', 'color', 'owner']
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`dataclasses.fields`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.fields) to pull out the fields, from the class or an instance. Then use the `.name` attribute to get the field names.

```
>>> from dataclasses import fields
>>> attributes = [field.name for field in fields(Car)]
>>> print(attributes)
['make', 'model', 'color', 'owner']
```